# Connect() is not passing state from store to child

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am "new to react". I am working on a project where I am creating three buttons named as *India*, *China*, *Russia*. On button click, text of paragraph changes.

For this, I have created 4 Presentational Components, 3 actions, 1 reducer and extra reducer for initial state.

I am trying to send **text** to paragraph, from `store` to `Presentational Component` via `connect()`. However, it's not working.

---

---

My code is as following:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers';
import App from './components/App';

const store = createStore(rootReducer);
console.log(store.getState());
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

---

actions/index.js

```
export const india = text => ({
  type: 'INDIA',
  text
});
export const china = text => ({
  type: 'CHINA',
  text
});
export const russia = text => ({
  type: 'RUSSIA',
  text
});
```

---

reducers/country.js

```
const initialState = {
  text: 'ABC',
  isIClicked: false,
  isCClicked: false,
  isRClicked: false
};
const country = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INDIA':
      return {
        text: action.text,
        isIClicked: true,
        isCClicked: false,
        isRClicked: false
      };
    case 'CHINA':
      return {
        text: action.text,
        isIClicked: false,
        isCClicked: true,
        isRClicked: false
      };
    case 'RUSSIA':
      return {
        text: action.text,
        isIClicked: false,
        isCClicked: false,
        isRClicked: true
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default country;
```

---

components/IndiaBtn.js

```
import React from 'react';

const IndiaBtn = ({ isIClicked, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={onClick}
      style={{
        color: isIClicked ? 'white' : 'black',
        backgroundColor: isIClicked ? 'blue' : 'white'
      }}
    >
      India
    </button>
  );
};
export default IndiaBtn;
```

---

components/ChinaBtn.js

```
import React from 'react';

const ChinaBtn = ({ isCClicked, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={onClick}
      style={{
        color: isCClicked ? 'white' : 'black',
        backgroundColor: isCClicked ? 'blue' : 'white'
      }}
    >
      China
    </button>
  );
};
export default ChinaBtn;
```

---

components/RussiaBtn.js

```
import React from 'react';

const RussiaBtn = ({ isRClicked, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={onClick}
      style={{
        color: isRClicked ? 'white' : 'black',
        backgroundColor: isRClicked ? 'blue' : 'white'
      }}
    >
      Russia
    </button>
  );
};
export default RussiaBtn;
```

---

components/display.js

```
import React from 'react';

const display = ({ text }) => {
  return <div style={{ padding: '16px' }}>{text}</div>;
};
export default display;
```

---

components/App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import IndiaBtnContainer from '../containers/IndiaBtnContainer';
import ChinaBtnContainer from '../containers/ChinaBtnContainer';
import RussiaBtnContainer from '../containers/RussiaBtnContainer';
import DisplayContainer from '../containers/DisplayContainer';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <span><IndiaBtnContainer /></span>
        <span><ChinaBtnContainer /></span>
        <span><RussiaBtnContainer /></span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <DisplayContainer />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

---

containers/IndiaBtnContainer.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import IndiaBtn from '../components/IndiaBtn';
import { india } from '../actions';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isIClicked: state.isIClicked
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onClick: () => dispatch(india('india'))
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(IndiaBtn);
```

---

containers/ChinaBtnContainer.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ChinaBtn from '../components/ChinaBtn';
import { china } from '../actions';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isCClicked: state.isCClicked
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onClick: () => dispatch(china('china'))
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChinaBtn);
```

containers/RussiaBtnContainer.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import RussiaBtn from '../components/RussiaBtn';
import { russia } from '../actions';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isCClicked: state.isCClicked
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onClick: () => dispatch(russia('russia'))
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RussiaBtn);
```

---

containers/DisplayContainer.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import display from '../components/display';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  text: state.text
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(display);
```

---

**Note:**

1. Sorry, for long code. But, I thought it is necessary to understand problem
2. Focus on `Container Component`s, `connect`, `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps`. According to me, problem must be there.

Comment: I think you have problem with the reducer. You are returning an array instead of object while you expect to get an object in the containers.

Comment: I have Converted it into object, thanks for pointing out that problem. However, Program still not working, click event not changing text in paragraph.

Comment: Where is this `reducer` - `const store = createStore(rootReducer)`? Plus when you have more than 1 reducer, you have to do something like this - `state.rootReducer.text` i.e. you have to specify which reducer you have to get the value of the state.

Comment: Thanks Yadav, It helped

Comment: Note, why create 3 Presentation Components/3 Container Components, which are essentially the same? Just create a single Presentation/Container Component combination and pass different values like `India`, `Russia`, `China` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reducer `returns an array` and hence `mapStateToProps` isn't giving you right values since you expect the state to be an object, what you need is

```
const initialState = {
          text: '',
          isIClicked: false,
          isCClicked: false,
          isRClicked: false,
}
const country = (state=initialState,action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INDIA':
          return {
          text: action.text,
          isIClicked: true,
          isCClicked: false,
          isRClicked: false,
          }
        case 'CHINA':
          return {
          text: action.text,
          isIClicked: false,
          isCClicked: true,
          isRClicked: false,
        }
       case 'RUSSIA':
         return {
          text: action.text,
          isIClicked: false,
          isCClicked: false,
          isRClicked: true,
        }
        default:
          return state
      }
export default country
```

Comment: I have Converted it into object, thanks for pointing out that problem. However, Program still not working, click event not changing text in paragraph

Comment: I have updated code as suggested by you, You can see changed code in question.

Comment: I have kept initial text of paragraph as "ABC". However, it is not getting displayed in paragraph, Nor it is changing onClick event.

Comment: you are creating the store from rootReducer, how exactly does it look. If you are using combineReducers, you might probably need to do state.country.text